# Activity vs Fragment : performance differences?

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, fragment

My question is simple : Is there a noticeable performance difference (for the system : cpu, memory allocaiton) between using Activity instead of Fragment (and vice-versa).

I have an simple app, and it is quite similar for me, to use Fragment or Activity (simple navigation, no actionbar, etc...), but I want to have to lightest possible one.

Answer (score 0):

Logically thinking if you have a fragment then you also must have an activity that will be hosting it. So having only activity seems to be lighter.

Comment: That was my opinion, but is the "fragment stack" heavy, and make a significant difference ?

Comment: I think that you won't notice the difference. Simply - don't use fragments if you don't need them. Even if it's not the performance case it's just an additional work.

Answer (score 0):

Using only one activity and lot of fragments is more efficient than using lot of activity. The difference in terms of performance are visible. You can try yourself to make an app with 5 screens for example: 5 activity vs 5 fragments. 
I advise to use more than one activity only when it's necessary for logical division of app's blocks.

Comment: Please explain why this is the case